# LightSwitch 2013 "DetailsPicker" when main data and picker data are in same table

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a table called Codes that is used for storing data relevant for lists (e.g. Buildings, Rooms, States, Countries, etc...).  The Building type in this table will have both a State and a Country so on the 'AddEditBuildings' screen I need pick lists for both.

The problem is, since all 3 of these data points reside in the same table there's no relationship and thus the standard way of creating the DetailsPicker does not work.  I've played around with using a pop-up (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733572.aspx#popup) but this just doesn't suit my needs.

I need the control to be a text box that when a user types into it the available options are filtered by their input.  Ideally, they could also expand to see all options.  Essentially I need it to work like the standard DetailsPicker.

Working on the State control, and taking from the link above, I've been able to make a textbox open the State pop-up on the 'keyup' event.  However, this has two problems:
1) It does not filter the options based on input text
2) The pop-up appears on top of the page (dialog) instead of attached to and under it.

Here's my code:

In Screen 'created' method:

```
screen.findContentItem("Query_Codes_States").dataBind("value.selectedItem", function (newValue) {
    //Whenever the State is selected, update the State value on the Code object
    screen.Code.Attr05 = newValue.CodeVal;
    screen.findContentItem('Code_Attr051').value = newValue.CodeVal;

    //Close popup, if one is open. 
    screen.closePopup();
});
```

State Text Box postrender method:

```
myapp.AddEditBuilding.Code_Attr051_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).keyup(function () {
        contentItem.screen.showPopup('StateList');
    });
}
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a suitable way to make this work using a popup.  Here's how to do it:

1. Add a data item to your screen for the data you want to pick from (named Query_Codes_States in this example)
2. Create a Popup in the Screen designer using the new data item.  In
   this example it's a list of States.
3. Click on the 'List' on the popup and then click on the Item Tap event in properties. Locate and select the Item Tap data item that was just added to the data items list.  Click 'Edit Execute Code' and type this code (adjust for your scenario):

   ```
   myapp.AddEditBuilding.States_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
   var newValue = screen.Query_Codes_States.selectedItem.CodeVal;
   screen.Code.setAttr05(newValue); // This is the State field on the Building entity.
   screen.closePopup();
   };
   ```
4. Locate the field you want to modify in the Screen designer.  In my case this is a text box called State.
5. In Properties, click 'Edit PostRender Code'.  Type this code (adjust
   for your scenario):

   ```
   myapp.AddEditBuilding.Attr05_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
   $(element).on('click', function (event) {
       contentItem.screen.showPopup('StatesPopup');
   })
   // Prevent typing in field
   $(element).on('keydown', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   })
   };
   ```

Note that this solution doesn't offer hint searching in the text box.  This would be great to have so if anyone can advise how to do this please let me know.

Hope this helps someone!